# GA - how to exclude URL parameters?

Tags: google-analytics

The number of unique URLs exceeds the daily limit in our Google Analytics [Analytics notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxfCv.png).
We tried to exclude URL Query Parameters in the View Settings but it doesn't work, GA continue to accept all this unique URLs. [URL Query Parameters excluded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8afxA.png).
Who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. SO is a coding specific platform. Probably the relevant audience for your question will be found at WM: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or WA: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Daily hits will be reprocessed after midnight, so if you set correct parameters in exclusion list you can see URL cleaned tomorrow.